# Button to pull up a menu like Spinner

Tags: android, button, spinner

I want to setup a button, that when clicked on will pull data from my database and fill a list (like when using a spinner). I've used popup menus before but haven't figured out a way to make them float (anyone know how to make the size a float and not pix). Is there a way to have a button pull up a list like a spinner or is it just better for me to change my ui to have the spinner instead of using an clickable image button?

Comment: What about using the button to pull up a listview of values from your Db?

Comment: I don't want to go away to another activity if I don't have to. It's for an equipment screen for a rpg game I'm making. So I feel it would be better UI wise to stay on the same activity and not have to go back once they select the equipment for that slot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a dialog that takes an adapter of your items

```
YourCustomAdapter adapter = new YourCustomAdapter(/**whatever args you need to get your content**/);
int selectedItem = -1; //somehow get your previously selected choice
Builder builder = new Builder(context);
builder.setSingleChoiceItems(adapter, selectedItem, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
    {
         //handle the item you clicked here

    }
};
builder.setTitle("Select Attachments").setCancelable(true);

Dialog dialog = builder.create();
```

Note that if you need to select multiple items there are methods for multiple choice items.
builder.setMultipleChoice...

Comment: TY for pointing me in the right direction. I'm using an AlertDialog that populates from a cursor instead of an adapter.